# インストールしたIntelRealsenseViewerが開きません．

Tags: windows-10

https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/releases/download/v2.35.2/Intel.RealSense.SDK-WIN10-2.35.2.1897.exe
このリンクからインストールをした中に入っていたIntel RealSense Viewerを開こうとするとクラッシュし開きません．
数秒開くということもなく，一切音沙汰がないような状態です．
同じ構成のPCを持つ友人に同じリンクからダウンロードしてもらい試したところ友人は開くことができました．
セーフモードで実行してもクラッシュします．
検証の結果，リンクの間違えやハードウェアの問題ではないかと思われます．
ご指導よろしくお願いします．

Answer (score 0):

[Intel RealSense Depth Camera D435を試してみました！](https://mag.switch-science.com/2018/04/19/intel-realsense-depth-camera-d435-handson/)　の記事はご覧になりましたか？
カメラは、USB3.0対応ポートにつながないといけないとか、いろいろと注意点がかかれているので、参考になるのではないかと思います。